# jQuery - Syntax Error

Tags: jquery

I am using the following to identify the current selected (active) link in a site:

```
 $(function(){
 var path = location.pathname.substring(1);
 if ( path )
 $('#sidebar_content a[@href$="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'selected');
 });
```

It appears to identify the path properly but also generates an error

> Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@href$="clinics/ohs_north_carolina"]

The page source does not show that the link has the class added.

Would appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[@attr]` style selectors were removed in jQuery 1.3. Remove the `@` symbol and it should work.

```
$('#sidebar_content a[href$="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'selected');
```

From the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors):

> Note: In jQuery 1.3 [@attr] style
>   selectors were removed (they were
>   previously deprecated in jQuery 1.2).
>   Simply remove the '@' symbol from your
>   selectors in order to make them work
>   again.

Comment: Hi Ayman, that certainly solved the problem. Thank you. One followup. Does this code apply the class="selected" attribute to the anchor tag? If so it does not show up in the source code.

Thanks,

Forrest

Comment: Hi fmz, it's better to use `.addClass('selected')` as it does not override existing classes. Also, JavaScript changes to the DOM tree are usually not visible in the "view source" window in browsers.

Comment: Hi Ayman, I appreciate your help here. I am trying to nail down a navigation issue that has been bugging me for days. I have an accordion navigation that I need to resolve. have it working on one level in that I can highlight the active link, but it is currently set manually. I would like to set that dynamically and this looks promising but appears to be lacking something. I would be happy to open another thread, but what I really need is an opportunity to work it through. Can you help?

Comment: Hi fmz, please open a new thread and provide details. Feel free to add a link here so that I can find it. I'm sure you will get help whether from me or someone else. :)

Comment: Hi Ayman, Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1829701/jquery-active-link-and-parent-relationship

Thanks again.