# jQuery - Active Link and Parent Relationship

Tags: jquery, navigation, hyperlink

I am working on a navigation for a site and need some guidance on dynamically adding a class to the active link. In addition, once that link is established and I need to reference back to the parent and have it "show".

This is what I am working with. The navigation is accordion style but does not use the Accordion UI.

```
<ul id="menu3">
    <li><a href="{site_url}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="drop" href="#">Information</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{site_url}information/audio">Audio</a></li>
            <li><a href="{site_url}information/video">Video</a></li>
            <li><a href="{site_url}information/presentations">Presentations</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="drop" href="#">Clinics</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{site_url}clinics/one">Office 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="{site_url}clinics/two">Office 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="{site_url}forms/">Forms</a></li>
    <li><a href="{site_url}success_stories/index">Success Stories</a></li>
```

Then I have a bit of jQuery to initially hide the submenu items:

```
$(function(){
$('ul#menu3 ul').hide();                
$('ul#menu3 > li > a.drop').click(function(){
$(this).parent().children('ul').toggle("slow");
   return false;
});
```

So far so good. Everything works.

Now I would like to dynamically highlight the active link and I tried using:

```
var path = location.pathname.substring(1);
if ( path )
$('ul#menu3 a[href$="' + path + '"]').attr('class', 'selected');
```

but it doesn't seem to be enough to add the correct class.

The last thing I need to do is to have the navigation open to the active group. For example if **Audio** is the current page, the **Information** section of the navigation accordion would be open to show the active link.

I would really appreciate some help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following just works fine for me. Also your add "selected" code works as expected. Comments provided inline. If question remain open... comment/ask.

```
$(function() {
    var pathname = location.pathname;
    var highlight;
    //highlight home
    if(pathname == "/")
        highlight = $('ul#menu3 > li:first > a:first');
    else {
        var path = pathname.substring(1);
        if (path)
            highlight = $('ul#menu3 a[href$="' + path + '"]');
    }
    highlight.attr('class', 'selected');

    // hide 2nd, 3rd, ... level menus
    $('ul#menu3 ul').hide();

    // show child menu on click
    $('ul#menu3 > li > a.drop').click(function() {
        //minor improvement
        $(this).siblings('ul').toggle("slow");
        return false;
    });

    //open to current group (highlighted link) by show all parent ul's
    $('a.selected').parents("ul").show();

    //if you only have a 2 level deep navigation you could
    //use this instead
    //$('a.selected').parents("ul").eq(0).show();
});
```

Comment: Hi Jitter, thank you for your response. It must be quite late in Vienna.

I tried this out and while most of the elements worked it stripped out all of the css styling I had in place. I am going to have to work with this a bit to see if I can get the jquery and css to play together nicely. I will be back.

Comment: It's 3:30 AM now ;). There should only be one statement which could mess with your CSS. Replace `highlight.attr('class', 'selected');` with `highlight.addClass('selected');` or be more specific which CSS styles get stripped.

Comment: Hi Jitter, this solution is so close to perfect I am really hoping to pull it together. 

I changed the it to highlight.addClass('selected'); but the original css is still gone. The styling is the same as it for the inline anchor tags - red links and gold hover instead of dark green background and white text.

Comment: Hi Jitter. My fault. I had a . instead of a # in the stylesheet. All fixed and working beautifully. Thank you so much for your kind assistance. I really appreciate you sharing your skill. Have a nice day!

Comment: Nice code! Helped me on a Drupal site where i'd made a custom menu. Thanks :)